# For whom are the answers to a question?

Tags: discussion

Today I got aware, that sometimes the author of a question has a more general title, such as "how to best do this or that" but expects some tactical help with the code he already has.

Yet, the topic as suggested by title (which will lead other readers to that post) is interesting in itself.

So the question arises, whether to "back down" from answering the question as stated in title and introduction and focus solely on the tactical problem or if it is of higher value to also add answers on topic, even if the solutions presented in the answers are not of interest for the author of the question.

I currently opted to add answers, which might as well be of interest to future readers, who might have different preferences or different requirements to the solution of the question than the author had.

Comment: This is a gray area... for example, if there's a question about something and the target is clearly one platform/environment, and you drop by later and add an unsolicited answer explaining how to do it in a completely different setting which has not previously been asked about, that may well receive as many "did you even read the question???" type responses as upvotes.  On the other hand, if if seems to be on its way to becoming the canonical question on the general subject and there are comments wondering how to do it in other circumstances, then it might well be a useful addition.

Comment: Another tactic might be to make sure you clearly cover the problem they are actually facing, even if you also chose to cover more general variations.

Comment: In my example it was about how to "robustly" associate an enum value with a function. Robustly was not clearly defined (which changes to the enum will be covered?). Yet, the author of the Q was determined to use templates. Yet, the path he chose has certain trade-offs which might not be desirable for others who have the same problem. So I showed 2 other ways how to do it.